# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when executing DirectoryInfo().GetFiles() from W3WP - Why?

Tags: c#, w3wp, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am running an ASP.NET webform which is trying to get the contents of a shared folder using `new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles(pattern)`. The application pool is set to run with a domain username, but at the point of execution it is impersonating my username. I am in a group which has *Full Control* access to all folders in the tree and has *Full Control* access the share. In addition, I have given `Everyone` *Read*, *Read & Execute* and *List folder contents* access to the folder tree and *Read & execute* access to the share.

However, when the statement is executed I get a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException:'Access to the path '\\server\share\sub1\sub2' is denied.`

Running SysInternals' Process Monitor, the event shows:

```
Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize
Disposition:    Open
Options:        Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open For Backup
Attributes:     n/a
ShareMode:      Read, Write Delete
AllocationSize: n/a
Impersonating:  <MyUsername>
```

Running a command window on the same server, I get no error when getting a directory listing of the folder or accessing any files in the folder.

What am I missing?

Why is the response, viewed in Process Monitor, **ACCESS DENIED** with the Operation given as **CreateFile**?

Short of giving `Everyone` *Full Control* (which I don't think would help) I can't think of any more permissions to grant.

Note, I also tried `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, pattern)` with the same result.

Update:

The Authentication on the web site is `Windows Authentication` and `ASP.NET impersonation`; anonymous access is disabled. The particular page does not override this.

Comment: Witch authentication do you use ? Try to add IISUSR to the folder

Comment: IIS_IUSRS is a server level account and cannot be added to domain groups. In any event, I'm not using anonymous access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a "double-hop" problem.

When you authenticate to the IIS server is the first 'hop'.
When IIS tries to access UNC, is the second hop which is not allowed.

IIS cannot in turn pass on your credentials to the UNC.

For more infos see this articles

[UNC Path Access Denied error](https://forums.iis.net/t/1230468.aspx)

[Double Hop Problem](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue)

Comment: That seems to be it. My workaround is to wrap the calls in `using (var wic = WindowsIndentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero) { ... }` which makes it use the application pool account instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting different results because your permissions are different than that of the account running your app in IIS.

Check the account that is running the application pool for your IIS site and make sure that account has access to the UNC path you are trying to access.

Comment: Both the account specified on the application pool and my account which is being impersonated and is the value returned by System.Environment.Username have full control on the share and all folders (and files).

Comment: I already stated in the original question that my account can access the UNC from the server and have since logged on as the application pool account and checked that it also has access from file explorer.